# The getter 'document' was called on null. Stream<QuerySnapshots> documents are not getting returned

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The defined `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`, i'm calling the uid from the class constructor

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> get hotels {
    // print("$uid in stream");

    return ownerCollection.document(uid).collection("hotels").snapshots();
  }
```

Setting the `StreamProvider`

```
class Hotels extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
      value: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).hotels,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
          title: Text("My Hotels"),
        ),
        body: HotelList())
      );
```

Here's my screen which is accessing the `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`

```
class HotelList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HotelListState createState() => _HotelListState();
}

class _HotelListState extends State<HotelList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final hotels = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);

    for(var doc in hotels.documents) {
      print(doc.data);
    }

     return Container();
  }
}
```

When i'm running it, it gives me the error: `The getter 'documents' was called on null , Reciever : null`

Please help, i wanna print the all documents from the subcollection "hotels".

Comment: add ur a screenshot of ur firestore, also make the `uid` is not null

Comment: it is printing data after some time or not ?

Comment: check for null of hotels.documents

`   final hotels = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);

    if(hotels.documents != null){
        for(var doc in hotels.documents {
        print(doc.data);
        }

        return Container();
    } else {
        // handle null
    }
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the error message "X was called on null" means that X isn't what is null, but whatever you called it on. In your case, this is the problem code:

```dart
final hotels = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);

for(var doc in hotels.documents) {
  print(doc.data);
}
```

The error is saying `documents` is getting called on null, which means `hotel` is null. That means that your provider fetching isn't working properly.

I haven't worked with the `StreamProvider` much, but if I had to guess it's because the first time your widget is built the source stream hasn't published any data yet, which makes sense as the source of the stream is an online service that needs time to connect and gather the data. This means there is no `QuerySnapshot` to return, and as such the `Provider.of` is returning null.

Normally you would fix this by giving the `StreamProvider` an initial value. Since the type is `QuerySnapshot`, though, I'm not sure what a sensical initial value would be other than, well, null. In that case, your only real option is to just handle the case where `hotel` is null.

```dart
final hotels = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);

if (hotels == null) {
  print('There is no data yet.');
  return Container();
}

...
```